# decltype() of captured variable in lambda: GCC bug and/or Clang bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, decltype

I've checked the [GCC buglist](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=decltype) and the [Clang buglist](https://llvm.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=decltype) and don't see anything relevant yet.

[This Wandbox link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/LYDzNhkbxN4A1Eaj) shows some C++11/C++14 code exercising `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` for various kinds of `x` captured by lambdas. GCC and Clang give different answers for this code. Which of them, if either, is correct?

Here's the offending snippet:

```
// inside main()
int i = 42;
int &j = i;
[j=j](){
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(j), GCC(const) int>::value,""); // A
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype((j)), const int&>::value,""); // B
}();
[=](){
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(j), int&>::value,""); // C
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype((j)), CLANG(const) int&>::value,""); // D
}();
```

where:

```
#ifdef __clang__
 #define CLANG(x) x
 #define GCC(x)
#else
 #define GCC(x) x
 #define CLANG(x)
#endif
```

I believe that in both cases, the thing that is actually captured<sup>(*)</sup> is a (non-const) `int` initialized to a copy of `j`'s value (that is to say, `i`'s value). Since the lambda isn't marked `mutable`, its `operator()` is going to be a `const` member function. With those prerequisites out of the way, let's proceed...

On line `// A`, GCC tells me that the decltype of the explicitly init-captured `j` is `const int`, when I'm almost positive that it ought to be `int` (per Clang).

On line `// B`, both compilers agree that `(j)` is an lvalue referring to a const int (since the lambda is not marked `mutable`); this makes perfect sense to me.

On line `// C`, both compilers agree that `j` is a name referring to the `int&` declared on line 2. This is a consequence of 5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda]/19, or rather, a consequence of the-thing-that-happens-when-that-clause-is-*not*-being-invoked. Inside a `[=]` lambda, the *name* `j` refers to the `j` in the outer scope, but the *expression* `(j)` refers to the `(j)` that would exist if `j` were to have been captured. I don't *fully* understand how this works or why it's desirable, but there it is. I'm willing to stipulate that this is not a bug in either compiler.

On line `// D`, Clang tells me that `(j)` is an lvalue referring to a const int, whereas GCC tells me that it's an lvalue referring to a *non-const* int. I'm pretty sure that Clang is right and GCC is wrong; `decltype((j))` should be the same whether `j` is captured implicitly or explicitly.

So:

- Are my explanations correct (according to the Standard)?
- Does the correct answer change between C++11 and C++14 (and C++1z)?
- Are `// A` and `// D` both bugs in GCC?
- Have these bugs been filed already?

---

<sup>(*)</sup> — In fact nothing is technically *captured* by the second lambda, because it doesn't use `j` in any evaluated context. That's why lines `// A` and `// C` give different answers. But I don't know any nice terminology for the-thing-that-*is*-being-done-to-`j`, so I'm just saying "captured".

Comment: GCC's misbehavior has been reported here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66672
I'm still interested in more in-depth answers about precisely what detail GCC is getting wrong, what other ramifications that might have, etc.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>I believe that **both** compilers are wrong for (A) and gcc is wrong for (D).</strike> 
I believe that gcc is wrong for (A) and (D), while clang is correct for both.

---

The relevant sections of [expr.lambda.prim] are:

> An *init-capture* behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form “auto *init-capture* ;”
>   whose declarative region is the *lambda-expression*’s *compound-statement*, except that:
>   — if the capture is by copy (see below), the non-static data member declared for the capture and the
>   variable are treated as two different ways of referring to the same object, which has the lifetime of the
>   non-static data member, and no additional copy and destruction is performed,

and

> Every *id-expression* within the *compound-statement* of a *lambda-expression* **that is an odr-use** (3.2) of an
>   entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the
>   closure type.

`decltype(j)` is not an odr-use of `j`, therefore no such transformation should be considered. Thus, in the case of `[=]{...}`, `decltype(j)` should yield `int&`. However, in the case of an *init-capture*, the behavior is as if there was a variable of the form `auto j = j;`, and the variable `j` refers to the same unnamed non-static data member with no such transformation necessary. So in the case of `[j=j]{...}`, `decltype(j)` should yield the type of that variable - which is `int`. It is definitely not `const int`. That is a bug.

The next relevant section:

> Every occurrence of `decltype((x))` where `x` is a possibly parenthesized *id-expression* that names an entity of automatic storage duration is treated as if `x` were transformed into an access to a corresponding data member of the closure type that would have been declared if `x` were an odr-use of the denoted entity.
>   *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> void f3() {
>     float x, &r = x;
>     [=] {                       // x and r are not captured (appearance in a decltype operand is not an odr-use)
>         decltype(x) y1;         // y1 has type float
>         decltype((x)) y2 = y1;  // y2 has type float const& because this lambda
>                                 // is not mutable and x is an lvalue
>         decltype(r) r1 = y1;    // r1 has type float& (transformation not considered)
>         decltype((r)) r2 = y2;  // r2 has type float const&
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

The example further illustrates that `decltype(j)` should be `int&` in the implicit copy case and also demonstrates that `decltype((j))` is treated as if `x` were the corresponding data member that would have been declared: which is `int const&` in both cases (as the lambda is not `mutable` and `j` is an lvalue). Your (C) and (D) cases exactly mirror the `r1`, `r2` declarations in the example. Which, while the examples are not normative, certainly suggests that gcc is in the wrong for having different behavior.

Comment: But for an *init-capture*, name lookup for `j` doesn't find the `int& j;`; it finds the `j` declared by the *init-capture*. See [expr.prim.lambda]/p11.

Comment: @T.C. Is that because the transformation into the unnamed member access doesn't need to happen?

Comment: If it happens, it refers to the unnamed member; it it doesn't happen, it refers to the thing implicitly declared by the init-capture. Either way, it's an `int`.